# Optimize Query: Group By while tracking Count

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6, index-tuning

Is there a better way to write this query? The query is taking too long (aprox 4sec)  The box table has about 8k records per day.

I've tried different Indexes but none seem to improve it so I'm thinking it's my query.

```
SELECT
boxType.id, sum(box.numBoxes) as totalBoxes,
count(DISTINCT box.employeeId) as totalEmployees
FROM box
INNER JOIN user as u ON u.id = box.userId
INNER JOIN jobBox as jobBox ON box.jobBoxId = jobBox.id
INNER JOIN boxType as bType ON bType.id = jobBox.boxTypeId
WHERE (u.clientId=?) AND (box.createdOn >= ?)
GROUP BY boxType.id

-- box
CREATE TABLE `box` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`employeeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`numBoxes` float NOT NULL,
`createdOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`jobBoxId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `User id_idx` (`userId`),
KEY `JobBoxFK_idx` (`jobBoxId`),
KEY `FK_5pomtj2u3uh6xq3qf7vmokc5k` (`employeeId`),
KEY `IDX_CreatedOn` (`createdOn`,`jobBoxId`),
CONSTRAINT `UserFK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)   ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `packFK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`jobBoxId`) REFERENCES `jobBox`   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `EmployeeFK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeId`) REFERENCES   `employee` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='.';

-- jobBox
CREATE TABLE `jobBox` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`jobId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`boxTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`createdOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `JobBoxFK_idx` (`jobId`),
KEY `BoxTypeID_idx1` (`boxTypeId`),
CONSTRAINT `jobBox_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`boxTypeId`) REFERENCES    `boxType` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `jobBox_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`jobId`) REFERENCES `job`  (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1937 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- boxType
CREATE TABLE `boxType` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- user
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`clientId` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
KEY `clients id_idx` (`clientId`),
CONSTRAINT `clients id` FOREIGN KEY (`clientId`) REFERENCES `client`   (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='  ';
```

Explain statement results

```
id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'box', NULL, 'range', 'EmployeeFK_1,packFK_1,IDX_CreatedOn', 'IDX_CreatedOn', '5', NULL, '33034', '100.00', 'Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'u', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE,clients id_idx', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'box.userId', '1', '14.04', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'jobBox', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,jobBox_ibfk_1', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'box.jobBoxId', '1', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'boxType', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,UnitTypesFK_idx', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'jobBox.boxTypeId', '1', '100.00', NULL
```

Any thoughts are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 4 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `box`:  `INDEX(userId, createdOn)`.

Then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if that is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @rick-james I will try this tonight. Note: i had userId originally but the query is actually by clientId.  I posted the Create and Explain info as requested (i changed table names to be more generic, hopefully i didnt mess anything up). I'll try INDEX(clientId, createdOn) tonight. The weird thing is that i cant get it to be "slow" on my local machine only on server. Server is running mysql 5.6 and local is 5.7.

Comment: `INNER JOIN user as u ON u.id = box.p` - `box` has no column called `p`; please fix this and any other typos.

Comment: Sorry Rick, I fixed the typo and double checked it all. I think we are good. i changed table names to be easier to understand but it makes it more prone to typos.  `u.id = box.userId` Thanks again for your help

Comment: Your answer made me start questioning my indexes.You pointed me to the Explain statement where I was able to see the key that was being used. I ended up deleting the pack key (jobBoxId) and adding a key of (userId, createdOn, and jobBoxId). The results are now acceptably under 0.8 seconds. Thank you again. I'll be monitoring in prod server tomorrow.